# How to change the order of Features in TFS 2013?

Tags: azure-devops

In TFS 2013 or Visual Studio Online, How to change the order of **Features**?

Comment: Drag and drop on the Feature Product backlog if you're a Visual Studio Online Advanced or MSDN Subscriber, by navigating to: https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_backlogs#_a=backlog&hub=Features

Comment: Do you mean that it does not work for the **Basic** account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For TFS 2013 the portfolio management is part of the "Full" Access level. and thus requires an MSDN subscription for your users. For lower level SKU's the portfolio backlogs are unavailable.

For Visual Studio Online, the portfolio management is part of the "Visual Studio Online Advanced" user plan and available to MSDN users. For lower level SKU's the portfolio backlogs are read-only. Changing the order is not available in read-only mode.

> [image]
>
> - <sup>(4)</sup> Agile Planning Tools include Agile Kanban and task boards and backlog and sprint planning.
> - <sup>(5)</sup> Read-Only

You can compare the different features per access levels here:

- [Visual Studio Online User Plans](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-user-plans-vs)
- [TFS Access levels explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159364.aspx)

A user can still manually influence the order by manipulating the field that's configured in the Process Template to represent the order:

- for Scrum: `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority`
- for MSF: `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank`

Since these fields are hidden in the UI by default, you'll probably need to create a custom work item query and manager the priorities from Excel using the Team Exploere add-in.